# How to prove this complex Inequality

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality

$$\left|\sum_{i=0}^\infty\gamma^ir_i-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\gamma^ir_i+{\gamma^nr_n \over 1-\gamma}\right)\right|\ge\left|\sum_{i=0}^\infty\gamma^ir_i-\left(\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\gamma^ir_i+{\gamma^kr_k \over 1-\gamma}\right)\right|$$
where $\gamma$ is a constant, $0<\gamma<1$, $n<k<\infty$, $r_i \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\gamma^ir_i < \infty$.

I'm trying to show that as long $k$ becomes larger the error between the true sequence $\gamma^0r_0+\gamma^1r_1+...$ and the estimated one $\sum_{i=0}^{k-1}\gamma^ir_i+{\gamma^kr_k \over 1-\gamma}$ becomes smaller.
See that all remaining terms is truncated using only one sample $r_k$ with the term ${\gamma^kr_k \over 1-\gamma}$. Additionally, if possible, I would like to know how much $r_k$, the last sampled $r$, can differ from the future values $r_{k+1}, r_{k+2},...$ to hold this inequality.

I simplified the above inequality to
$\left|\sum^\infty_{i=n}\gamma^i(r_i-r_n)\right|\geq\left|\sum^\infty_{i=k}\gamma^i(r_i-r_k)\right|$, removed the absolute by squaring both side of the inequality and I get $$\sum_{i=n+1}^k\gamma^i(r_i-r_n)^2\geq{\gamma^{k+1}(r_k^2-r_n^2)\over1-\gamma}$$

In the limit as $k\rightarrow\infty$ the right side of the inequality is $0$ and the left side is the squaring sum which will be a number greater or equal to zero, so the inequality becomes true as $k\rightarrow\infty$.

and what for $k < \infty$, e.g., $k = 1+n$, $k = 2+n$, $k = 3+n$...

let state that $r_i$ is a variable sampled from normal distribution where the mean is $\mu$ and the standard deviation is $\sigma$.

What now?

Comment: What about $r_i$?

Comment: I think we need more information. What if the infinite series do not converge?

Comment: I think that is not possible if $\gamma < 1$.

Comment: @Davi quite a lot is possible. Take for eg $r_i = \frac1{\gamma^i}$

Comment: That's quite a stretch, if you allow divergent series on both sides. Where is the question from? Are there no other conditions explicit or implied in the reference?

Comment: @Macavity $\sum_{i=0}^\infty\gamma^ir_i < \infty$